# Handling ListView's AddListener

Tags: java, list, listview, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to listen for add events for a ListView's items. I've attempted to do this by trying `getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TYPE>()`, but it doesn't have the return type that I want. It returns a `List<? extends TYPE>` whereas I want a `List<TYPE>`. How can I get it to the proper type, and not a subclass of it? Maybe something like: `.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener`, which has a defined newValue for the type that I need?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, you can still access the fields of TYPE.  At least I don't see a problem.  I'm guessing you're not using the change and trying for something like newValue.  It doesn't work like that.  [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html)

Comment: It sounds like you're concerned about the difference between a `javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener` and a `javafx.collections.ListChangeListener`. The former calls the listener with the old value and new value, whereas the latter calls the listener with a `ListChangeListener.Change`. That seems to have all the information you need. Are you concerned that the type is `ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TYPE>` ? If so, it should still work, since reading from anything `<? extends TYPE>` is compatible with `TYPE`. But maybe you should clarify.